# how to get this hidden field?

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I have this piece of HTML:

```
<li class="hidden-xs-inline">
 <a class='page-link' href="/acne-scars-treatment/answers?page=226" data-page="226">
</a>
</li>
```

how could I get the number `226` using Java with Jsoup?

I used this code:

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(topic_link).get();

Elements elements = doc.select("li.hidden-xs-inline > a.page-link");

return elements.text();
```

but it didn't return that number I want to get!

any idea!?

Answer (score 0):

The data you require is not in the elements body so 'text()' won't work. Try:

```
elements.attr("data-page");
```

For more information please look at:
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html

Answer (score 0):

see below:

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.List;


/**
 add following dependencies to pom.xml

           <dependency>
              <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
               <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
               <version>1.10.2</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
               <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
               <version>4.5.3</version>
           </dependency>

 */
public class JsoupExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {

        String HTMLSTring = "<li class=\"hidden-xs-inline\">\n" +
                " <a class='page-link' href=\"/acne-scars-treatment/answers?page=226\" data-page=\"226\">\n" +
                "</a>\n" +
                "</li>";

        Document html = Jsoup.parse(HTMLSTring);

        Elements hiddenElements = html.body().getElementsByClass("hidden-xs-inline");

        Elements pageLinkElements = hiddenElements.get(0).getElementsByClass("page-link");
        String href = pageLinkElements.get(0).attr("href");

        List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(href), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        for (NameValuePair param : params) {
            System.out.println(param.getName() + " : " + param.getValue());  //page : 226
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, gave me the following error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0. 

plus how to add pom.xml in Netbeans?

Comment: in Netbeans you have to add the jar files to the classpath.  the jar files can be found here https://jsoup.org/download
https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi